# Create new records using Visualforce action and AggregateResult

Tags: apex, visualforce, map, controller-extension, aggregate

I have a need to aggregate values from child records, group them by an Id field on that record and then create a new record for each corresponding ID.

I have 2 objects, Sesaco_Contract__c and Payee__c. The two are linked by a lookup on the Payee__c object (MA__c). There is an amount field on the Payee object that I need to aggregate and that is Value_for_Partial__c. Lastly, There is a lookup to Account on that object as well called Payee__c (inconveniently named, I know).

I want to have a button on my Sesaco_Contract__c record that I can click and it will do the following: summarize the Value_for_Partial__c values and group them by the Payee__c (Account) Id's that are associated with that Sesaco_Contract__c record. I then  want to create an Accounts Payable record (c2g__codaPurchase_Invoice__c) with the Account field being populated with the Payee__c Id and the value field being populated with the Aggregated Value_for_Partial__c amount.

I think I'm close, but could be very far off. I am not sure. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Extension:

```
    public class createAPfromMAextension {

    private Id MAId;
    private Map<Id,AggregateResult> payMap;

    public createAPfromMAextension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        Sesaco_Contract__c ma = (Sesaco_Contract__c)stdController.getRecord();
        MaId = ma.Id;
        System.debug('=========== What is the MA Id?' + MAId);

        List<Payee__c> payList = [SELECT Payee__c, Value_for_Partial__c from Payee__c WHERE MA__c = :MaId];
        System.debug('===============is PayList Empty?' +' '+payList.isEmpty());
        payMap = new Map<Id,AggregateResult>([SELECT Payee__c, SUM(Value_for_Partial__c) valtotal from Payee__c Where Payee__c.Id IN :payList Group By Payee__c]); 
        System.debug('======is Paymap empty?' +' ' + payMap.isEmpty());
    }

    public PageReference createAP() {

        // if(ma.Approved__c != null && ma.Payment_Request_Date__c != null){

        List<c2g__codaPurchaseInvoice__c> apList = new List<c2g__codaPurchaseInvoice__c>();
        for(AggregateResult ag : payMap.values()){
            c2g__codaPurchaseInvoice__c ap = new c2g__codaPurchaseInvoice__c();
            ap.c2g__Account__c = string.valueOf(ag.get('Payee__c'));
            ap.c2g__AccountInvoiceNumber__c = 'Please Set this number manually' + ' ' + system.Datetime.now(); // added "now" since this has to be a unique value
            ap.c2g__InvoiceDate__c = system.date.today();
            ap.c2g__DueDate__c = system.date.today().addDays(30);
            ap.c2g__InvoiceDescription__c = string.valueOf(ag.get('valtotal'));
            aplist.add(ap);
        }
       database.insert(aplist,true);
    return new PageReference('/a2s/o');
        //}
        //else return new Pagereference ('/' + MaId);
    }
}
```

VF Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Sesaco_Contract__c" extensions="createAPfromMAextension" action="{!createAP}">
```

Here is a screenshot of my execute log and the error message I'm getting:

[image]

Error Message on VF Page:

**Row with null Id at index: 0 **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably close. You can't call an action method that expects a parameter, and you do not have anything for your methods to talk to one another. Also, you probably want to return something at the end so the page does not just sit there. Try this:

```
public class createAPfromMAextension {

    private Id MAId;
    private List<AggregateResult> payMap;

    public createAPfromMAextension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        Sesaco_Contract__c ma = (Sesaco_Contract__c)stdController.getRecord();
        MaId = ma.Id;

        List<Payee__c> payList = [SELECT Id, Value_for_Partial__c, Payee__c from Payee__c WHERE Id = :ma.Id];

        payMap = new List<AggregateResult>([SELECT Payee__c, SUM(Value_for_Partial__c) valtotal from Payee__c Where Id IN :payList Group By Payee__c Order By Payee__c ]); 

    }

    public PageReference createAP() {
        PageReference p = null;

        List<c2g__codaPurchaseInvoice__c> apList = new List<c2g__codaPurchaseInvoice__c>();
        for(AggregateResult ag : payMap){
            c2g__codaPurchaseInvoice__c ap = new c2g__codaPurchaseInvoice__c();
            ap.c2g__Account__c = string.valueOf(ag.get('Payee__c'));
            ap.c2g__AccountInvoiceNumber__c = 'Please Set this number manually' + ' ' + system.Datetime.now();
            ap.c2g__InvoiceDate__c = system.date.today();
            ap.c2g__DueDate__c = system.date.today().addDays(30);
            ap.c2g__InvoiceDescription__c = string.valueOf(ag.get('valtotal'));
            aplist.add(ap);
        }
       database.insert(aplist,true);
    return new PageReference('/' + MAId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @CyberJus, I've input that code and it executes without any errors which is good, the new records aren't being created though. After looking at the logs, it looks like my queries aren't returning any rows.

Getting closer! A little debugging yet to do still.

Comment: Harder to help you there without seeing the data and the schema, but at least you are closer. Try running the queries in the developer console/workbench/IDE.

Comment: It looks like it's breaking down at my "payMap" part of the code. Not sure where the error is in that part of the code.

Comment: You mean that query is not returning any values?

Comment: Well I've added some debug statements to the code and it fails before I can get to my Map debugging line. I've attached the log and updated my code above.

Comment: I am guessing one of the Payee__c values is null which is giving you the exception when converting it to a map. Per your code, the map is unnecessary anyways. I updated my solution to a list instead. Try that instead.

Comment: You sir, are a gentleman and a scholar. Much, much appreciated! That worked perfectly.